# filtered date doesn't show after edit the column date format - Laravel Yajra Datatable

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, lumen, yajra-datatable

I use laravel 8 + lumen rest api server and little bit confused because when i consume `timestamp` and parse it to localize format date on laravel side, also separated the `display` and `timestamp` for the js side datatables, the `editColumn()`it make the filtered search doesn't work because the main of search params is from the timestamp i was set before but on the view i saw it use display side, so how i can make the both filtered(search) and sort work ?

response data :

```php
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id_role" => 1
    "nama_role" => "super.admin"
    "created_at" => "2021-11-02T07:32:00.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-11-02T07:32:00.000000Z"
    "created_by" => "self"
    "updated_by" => "self"
  ]
  .. => ...
]
```

the column i was sorted was created_at and updated at.

RoleController.php

```php
<?php
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $raw = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . Cookie::get('access_token')])->get(env('API_URL') . '/v1/kelola-role/role');
        $data = $raw->json('data');
        $status = $raw->json('status');
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if ($status == 'success') {
                return DataTables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->editColumn('created_at', function ($e) {
                        return [
                            'display' => Carbon::parse($e['created_at'])->format('d/m/Y'),
                            'timestamp' => Carbon::parse($e['created_at'])
                        ];
                    })
                    ->editColumn('updated_at', function ($e) {
                        return [
                            'display' => Carbon::parse($e['updated_at'])->format('d/m/Y'),
                            'timestamp' => Carbon::parse($e['updated_at'])
                        ];
                    })
                    ->make(true);
            }

            return abort(401);
        }
        return view('pages.pengaturan.kelola-role');
    }
```

the view :

```html
<table class="table" id="dataRole" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Nama Role</th>
            <th>Dibuat Pada</th>
            <th>Diupdate Pada</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Nama Role</th>
            <th>Dibuat Pada</th>
            <th>Diupdate Pada</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

the js side :

```js
       $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            $("#dataRole").DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "",
                    dataSrc: function(json) {
                        barDone();
                        return json.data;
                    }
                },
                columns: [{
                        data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                        name: 'DT_RowIndex',
                        orderable: false,
                        searchable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'nama_role',
                        name: 'nama_role'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'created_at.timestamp',
                        data: {
                            _: 'created_at.display',
                            sort: 'created_at.timestamp'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'updated_at.timestamp',
                        data: {
                            _: 'updated_at.display',
                            sort: 'updated_at.timestamp'
                        }
                    },
                ],
                responsive: true,
                fixedHeader: true,
                select: {
                    style: "multi"
                },
                language: {
                    url: '{{ env('APP_URL') }}/id.json',
                    processing: "<div id='loadercontainer'><div class='d-flex justify-content-center text-secondary' id='loader'><div class='spinner-border' role='status'><span class='sr-only'>Loading...</span></div></div></div>"
                },
                dom: '<"row"<"col-12 col-sm-6 py-0"l><"col-12 col-sm-6 py-0 pt-2 pt-sm-0"fr><"col-12"t><"col-12 d-flex justify-content-between"ip>>',
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                },
            });
        });
```

created_at sort view just work

[image]

but when i search it doesn't work
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also need to transform the search on the query level. Try using [filterColumn](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/filter-column) to modify how the package will search on the edited column.

In some cases, we need to implement a custom search for a specific column. To achieve this, you can use `filterColumn` api.

Comment: according the documentation the ```filterColumn``` using query / model, but i consume data ```array``` response from rest api, so i must transform the data to the query level ? and no other way to direct to manipulate the array filter using yajra datatables?
anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: what about 'Y-m-d' format?

Comment: yeah its work for 'Y-m-d' and 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format only, when i try another format the filtered search still not showing, including the localized format